# Zipping the files in Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have used `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` in **LOG4J**, it splits the files based on the size. My question here is that I want to zip all the files within a date into single folder.

> Example:
>
> log_20160709_1.txt
>
> log_20160709_2.txt
>
> log_20160709.3.txt

all the above files have to zip into **log_20160709.zip**.

I am able to zip the individual files but I want all to be in single zip folder.

Please provide the suggestion for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of options to do that

1. Use [TimeBasedRollingPolicy](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html)

Automatic file compression

TimeBasedRollingPolicy supports automatic file compression. This feature is enabled if the value of the FileNamePattern option ends with .gz or .zip.
[image]

2. write a batch job which will run at End Of the Day Say midnight and zips all files of the day into a single zip file.

Comment: If we follow option 1, size of the log file will be so big. Is it possible to do both 'SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy' and 'TimeBasedRollingPolicy' and perform zip operation @Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
<param name="FileNamePattern" value="/wombat/foo.%d{yyyy-MM-hh}.gz"/>
```